# Fetch URL from instagram bio without logging in

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

i want to fetch a URL from bio with php.
URL: https://www.instagram.com/sukhcha.in/ (It can be anyone's profile)
I tried using simple_html_dom but it always shows https error while fetching html from url.

Comment: Have you tried [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the contents of the page ?

Comment: @roberto06 can you please give me code for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURLto get data.

```
    $url = 'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMO0460:1:US';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Debug data

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($curl_response);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Close curl

```
    curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

As advised in my comment, you should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), because it supports HTTPS protocol :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // Timeout (0 : no timeout)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // Do not download header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'); // creates user-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // do not output content
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // do not check HTTPS host (very important, if you set it to true, it probably won't work)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/sukhcha.in/');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Then you have to use XPath on your `$content` variable to extract the part you want.